# Get specific object dimensional position from image

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, opencv, image

I need to get specific object like logo dimensional position from an image. I checked open-cv, pillow package etc but it does not help to me. Can anyone advice which is the best process to do this? Do we need deep learning for it or we can do it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a logo sample to detect. In that case you can use OpenCV template detection. You need to pass source logo and target image.
Link - [Template Matching using OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)